# How to disable SQL Server 2008 R2 Database copying

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security, sql-server-2008-r2

I've SQL Database that I've to install to a client. I really don't want my database tables and other components exposed. The thing is that I've limited work experience on SQL Server 2008 R2 security setting. Besides, is it possible to disable physical database copy from the folder where the database is located?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No, it's not possible in any meaningful way. You might be able to use some form of encryption to make simple accesss attempts harder, but with the key on the same machine it's really not secure.

Comment: How about disabling database copy?

Comment: Not that I can think of on the same machine, the problem is you can attach to the data directly anyway and bypass any security settings. At the end of the data if someone zipped your database straight from Windows and sent it to me I'd be able to view it and do whatever else.

Comment: No, not possible in a sensible way. Unless the user has no admin rights and no way to make a backup, which totlaly goes against what databases should contain and how they should be used. Live with it.

Comment: If the user is an administrator on the machine containing the database, then there's nothing you can do that will 100% prevent them obtaining access to the database, if they're determined enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the SQL server under its own user (good practice for security anyway), and grant only that user permissions to the directory where the physical database is stored. This will prevent some other limited user from being able to copy the physical database files; but will not stop administrators.

Administrative users have `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege`, so they can overwrite whatever permissions you may have set.

Of course, if the client has physical access to the machine, they effectively own the data on that machine; there's nothing you can do about that. A good software security system starts with a good physical security system.